# In Perl, XML::Simple is not able to dereference multi dimensional associative array parsed by Data::Dumper

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing, perl-module

Following is the xml file that I want to parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<topic id="yerus5" xmlns:ditaarch="http://dita.oasis-open.org/architecture/2005/">



<title/>
  <shortdesc/>
  <body>
<p><b>CCU_CNT_ADDR: (Address=0x004 Reset=32'h1)</b><table id="table_r5b_1xj_ts">
<tgroup cols="4">
  <colspec colnum="1" colname="col1"/>
  <colspec colnum="2" colname="col2"/>
  <colspec colnum="3" colname="col3"/>
  <colspec colnum="4" colname="col4"/>
  <tbody>
        <row>
          <entry>Field</entry>
          <entry>OFFSET</entry>
          <entry>R/W Access</entry>
          <entry>Description</entry>
        </row>
        <row>
          <entry>reg2sm_cnt</entry>
          <entry>15:0</entry>
          <entry>R/W</entry>
          <entry>Count Value to increment in the extenral memory at the specified location.
            Default Value of 1. A Count value of 0 will clear the counter value</entry>
        </row>
        <row>
          <entry>ccu2bus_endianess</entry>
          <entry>24</entry>
          <entry>R/W</entry>
          <entry>Endianess of the data structure bit</entry>
        </row>
        <row>
          <entry>ccu_lane_sel</entry>
          <entry>25</entry>
          <entry>R/W</entry>
          <entry>ccu_lane_sel bit. Indicates the lane selection bit of the 32-bit location to
            update</entry>
        </row>
        <row>
          <entry>ccu_rdinvalid</entry>
          <entry>26</entry>
          <entry>R/W</entry>
          <entry>ccu_rdinvalid bit. Indicates if the read value from the bus needs to be stored
            or not.</entry>
        </row>
      </tbody>
    </tgroup>
  </table></p>


</body>
</topic>
```

After running following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl


# use module
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

# create object
$xml = new XML::Simple(); #(KeyAttr=>[]);

# read XML file
$data = $xml->XMLin("test.xml");

# access XML data
print Dumper($data);



# dereference hash ref



    # foreach $b (@{$p->{b}})
    # {

# }
foreach $body (@{$data->{body}})
{
 foreach $p (@{$body->{p}})
 {
     foreach $table (@{$p->{table}})
     {

        foreach $tgroup (@{$table->{tgroup}})
        {

            foreach $tbody (@{$tgroup->{tbody}})
            {

                foreach $row (@{$tbody->{row}})
                {
                    foreach $entry ((@{$row->{entry}})->[3])
                    {
                    print $entry,"\n";
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

I am getting this error: **Not an ARRAY reference at ppfe.pl line 28.** (at `foreach $body (@{$data->{body}})`)

I want to access each data of the `<entry></entry>`. Above code only is only accessing the 'Description' column. How to do that?

With reference to above question,

I am not able to extract details particularly for each `<b></b>` text. Following is sample output:

```
Name: CCU_CNT_ADDR: (Address=0x004 Reset=32'h1)
Field: reg2sm_cnt 
OFFSET: 15:0 
Access: R/W 
Description: Count Value to increment in the extenral memory at the specified location. Default Value of 1. A Count value of 0 will clear the counter value 
Filed: ccu2bus_endianess 
OFFSET: 24 
Access: R/W 
Description: Endianess of the data structure bit 
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
Name: CCU_STAT_ADDR: (Address=0x008 Reset=32'h0) 
Field: fifo_cnt 
.
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
```

Comment: Start by adding `use strict` and `use warnings`.

Comment: What's your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use [`XML::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.20/lib/XML/Simple.pm).

Even `XML::Simple` says "don't use `XML::Simple`".

> The use of this module in new code is discouraged. Other modules are available which provide more straightforward and consistent interfaces.

Try instead something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

XML::Twig->new(
    'twig_handlers' => {
        'entry' => sub { print $_ ->text, "\n" }
    }
)->parsefile ('your_file.xml');
```

This will print the text content of all the `entry` elements, which appears to be what you're trying to do?

`XML::Twig` has two really handy mechanisms - one of using a `twig_handler` to find and print nodes matching a spec - this works 'as you go' which is particularly useful when handling large XML, or if you want to edit it before processing.

However, it also allows you to 'handle' data afterwards:

```
my $twig = XML::Twig->new( 'pretty_print' => 'indented_a' )->parsefile('your_xml_file');

foreach my $element ( $twig -> get_xpath ("//entry") )
{
    print $element ->text, "\n";
}
```

Or you could use a full path to the node as you're doing above:

```
$twig->root->get_xpath("body/p/table/tgroup/tbody/row/entry") )
```

In response to your question though:

> Above code only is only accessing the 'Description' column. How to do that?

That's because you're doing this:

```
foreach $entry ((@{$row->{entry}})->[3])
```

E.g. trying to get the 4th element in the `entry` array, which is `Description`.

With reference to the comments - I'd suggest you convert your 'entries' into a hash outside the XML data structure.

Like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

use Data::Dumper;

my @headers;

my $column_to_show = 'Field';

sub process_row {
    my %entries;

    my ( $twig, $row ) = @_;
    my @row_entries = map { $_->text } $row->children;
    if (@headers) {
        @entries{@headers} = @row_entries;
        print $column_to_show, " => ", $entries{$column_to_show}, "\n";
    }
    else {
        @headers = @row_entries;
    }
}

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    'pretty_print' => 'indented_a',
    twig_handlers  => { 'row' => \&process_row }
)->parsefile ( 'your_file.xml' );
```

What this does is:

- fire that handler on each `row` element.
- extract the `entry` subelements (and their text) into an array. `@row_entries`.
- Use the "header" row to turn that into a hash.
- Print the hash value that matches a specific key `$column_to_show`.

Depending on whether you're doing any more with the data than print it, you can turn that into a hash of arrays or similar.

Or you could just print `$row_entries[3]` instead of course ;).

Comment: You really like to fight against XML::Simple :D I challenge you to give a talk like SawyerX's _CGI.pm must die!_ on the next YAPC::EU in Granada :)

Comment: Hah, I'd be tempted. I mean, if nothing else - `XML::Twig` has `simplify` which lets it be backwards compatible with `XML::Simple`. But otherwise is just Much Better at representing the nature of XML - which perl can't really do natively, thanks to XML not having arrays, and perl not having duplicate key hashes.

Comment: See you in Granada then. I bet @Mirod will be there as well.

Comment: Having googled, I suspect not this year, but will investigate next.

Comment: Thanks Sobrique! It works :) But the code is printing all the entries simultaneously. I want each and every entry text to be access separately e.g.  get only the 4th element in the entry array, which is Description. or get only 2nd lement in the entry array, which is OFFSET.

Comment: OK. Amended answer slightly.

Comment: Thank you Sobrique for your quick response! The solution you have provided, works for me :)

Comment: Added one more query..above in comment section for question.

Comment: I would suggest asking a new question. It's hard to tell what you mean from a comment.

Comment: OK. Amended the question.

Comment: No, I mean literally - if you ask it as a separate question, then you'll get other people looking at it, and you may elicit better answers. I'm unclear exactly what you mean by it. But you should be able to `get_xpath ( '//b' )` for example.

Comment: I find it's almost always clearer and more straightforward to build an XML document and query it with XPath expressions rather than use the `XML::Twig` callbacks, which are meant primarily for keeping huge XML documents manageable

Answer (score 0):

It is always swifter and more accurate to use a proper XML parsing module that will allow you to access the XML data using XPath expressions

Here's a solution using [`XML::Twig`][XML::Twig]

I wasn't sure what you meant about the **bold** fields in `<b>`...`</b>` as there is only one in the example data you show, but I've accessed that using the XPath `//body/p/b` and printed it at the start of the output

The rest of the output is the values of the `<entry>` elements in each `<row>` which I access using `//table/tgroup/tbody/row`. The contents of the first row are used as field names to label subsequent values

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use open qw/ :std :encoding(UTF-8) /;

use XML::Twig;
use List::Util qw/ max /;
use List::MoreUtils qw/ pairwise /;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new;
$twig->parsefile('topic.xml');

say $twig->findvalues('//body/p/b');
say '';

my (@fields, $size);
for my $row ( $twig->findnodes('//table/tgroup/tbody/row') ) {

  unless ( @fields ) {
    @fields = map "$_:", $row->findvalues('entry');
    $size = max map length, @fields;
    next;
  }

  my @values = $row->findvalues('entry');
  say for pairwise { sprintf '%-*s %s', $size, $a, $b } @fields, @values;
  say '---';
}
```

#### output

```
CCU_CNT_ADDR: (Address=0x004 Reset=32'h1)

Field:       reg2sm_cnt
OFFSET:      15:0
R/W Access:  R/W
Description: Count Value to increment in the extenral memory at the specified location.
            Default Value of 1. A Count value of 0 will clear the counter value
---
Field:       ccu2bus_endianess
OFFSET:      24
R/W Access:  R/W
Description: Endianess of the data structure bit
---
Field:       ccu_lane_sel
OFFSET:      25
R/W Access:  R/W
Description: ccu_lane_sel bit. Indicates the lane selection bit of the 32-bit location to
            update
---
Field:       ccu_rdinvalid
OFFSET:      26
R/W Access:  R/W
Description: ccu_rdinvalid bit. Indicates if the read value from the bus needs to be stored
            or not.
---
```